# Setting Remote Desktop to allows IPv6 connections

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, ipv6

**Setup:**

Basically I have 3 machines (2 virtual and 1 physical) that I would like to be able to RDP in to from outside my NAT (a router).

The VMs are Windows 7 and Windows XP, both fully patched with Teredo installed and working, both running in VirtualBox (their host also has Teredo working, though I'm not sure if that matters).  They both have bridged network adapters with promiscuous mode enabled.

The physical machine is Windows 7 fully patched with an HFS server running on it and a dynamic DNS set up for my public IPv4 address and port forwarded.  It also has Teredo installed and working.

**Symptoms:**

- According to http://test-ipv6.com/ all 3 have public IPv6 addresses, and they can all connect to `http://ipv6.google.com/`.
- I can ping the XP VM from the host it's running on but I cannot ping it from any other machine.
- Also, I cannot ping either of the other machines from anywhere.
- I cannot connect to any of them over RDP from IPv6, however I can connect to all of them through IPv4.

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess whatever IPv6 access you have is *not* Teredo. Teredo will not do AAAA DNS lookups on Windows, meaning http://ipv6.google.com/ should not work.

I would highly recommend a managed tunnel service over Teredo or even 6to4. Teredo/6to4 is almost impossible to debug and is very unreliable. I recommend setting up a tunnel with [Hurricane Electric](http://tunnelbroker.net/).

### Setting up a managed tunnel:

How to set up an HE tunnel depends on your router. Newer routers that are IPv6 compatible may have options to do the tunnel right there or you can load up OpenWRT to do it. `6in4` tunnel or `sit` encapsulation are the options to look for.

If your router cannot setup the tunnel itself, you will need the router to forward protocol 41 (6in4 traffic) to a machine that can. Either by setting up that forward rule specifically if available in your router, or by setting that machine as the DMZ host.

Hurricane electric can help you from there on setup up the tunnel on that host be it Linux or Windows.

Comment: I have heard of Hurricane Electric before, but was not sure how to set it up.  Could you please link me to a guide to set up what I am trying to do?

Comment: @Garrett, See my edit. I can find a guide if I knew your setup. What router do you have?

Comment: My router is a THOMSON TG585 v7, and I don't think that my ISP supports IPv6, but I'm not sure.